# jsLint Expected {

Tags: javascript, coding-style, jslint

Given the following

```
for(var i=0; i< data.cats.length; i++) list += buildCategories(data.cats[i]);
```

jsLint tells me

```
Expected '{' and instead saw 'list'.
```

Is there an actual disadvantage to using the shorter notation instead of wrapping it it curly braces?

Comment: if you are sure you don't want that check, then simply change the hinting configuration by supplying `"curly":false,`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is defensive programming - using curly brackets clearly defines which statements are intended to be associated with the `for`.

If you don't use curly brackets, at a later point someone might mistakenly add another statement underneath `list += buildCategories...` expecting it to get executed with the `for` loop as well.

Comment: I don't agree with all of Crockford's style rules, but I'm 100% with this one.

Comment: This is annoying to me because I use for-if. `for(var k in obj) if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {...}` (or with other filters) is very, very useful, but the pattern raises this warning. I think this is as legit as `else if` (else would require braces otherwise)

Comment: I am debugging several thousand lines of someone else's code, so I don't have the luxury of deciding whether or not to use "proper style". Sure would be nice to suppress these errors, especially since JSLint won't progress once encountered...

Comment: @FábioSantos jslint also complains about `else if` and asks you to change it to `else { if`

Comment: @bluesmoon Aren't you wrong about that? I've just checked, and it doesn't complain.

Comment: Maybe it likes you more than it likes me.

Answer (score 7):

> *"Is there an actual disadvantage to using the shorter notation..."*

It may be the source of  bugs if you're not careful about your coding, but omitting them provides cleaner code IMO, and if you adhere to consistent and well thought programming standards, omitting them won't be an issue.

For example, when I have nested `if/else` statements that are otherwise able to exclude the braces, I prefer to balance the `else`s over using braces.

```
if (condition)
    if (condition2)
        inner_if()
    else ;
else
    outer_if()
```

That code is still cleaner than this IMO...

```
if (condition) {
    if (condition2) {
        inner_if();
    }
} else {
    outer_if();
}
```

If someone things they can add another statement to an `if` or `else`, then that's an issue of understanding that needs to be fixed.

So really it's just a question of what standards are to be used. Taking advantage of curly braces is certainly one valid option, but we shouldn't be too dogmatic about it.

---

If you want a more configurable tool, you could consider [jsHint.com](http://jshint.com/) instead.

Comment: @AdamRackis: All my answers are now going CW. I guess I just like it better that way.

Comment: Tired of the rep rat race, eh?  :)

Comment: @AdamRackis: Yeah, now that I have a good set of privileges here, I don't really care about the rep. I'd rather CW it and let others feel more comfortable about adding value if they wish.

Comment: That's really cool.  The only other privilege is at 20K, and that's only expanded ability to delete stuff.  So you're pretty well maxed out.

Comment: @AdamRackis: Yeah, that much power would probably just go to my head. ;)

Answer (score 3):

JSLint checks for following good code style. Inserting curly braces is always good style because it is obvious where the code belongs to. And that it is shorter is not really an argument since most minifiers take care of that anyway.